# R function condition on parameter

Tags: r, dplyr

In an R function using {dplyr}, I would like to change the data frame used based on the value of another parameter of the function.

Example :

```
library(dplyr)

iris2 <- iris

myfunction <- function(param) {
  
  result <- 
    
    if (param=="one") {
      iris } else if (param=="two") {
        iris2 }
  %>% count(Species) 

return(result)
}

myfunction(param="one")
myfunction(param="two")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close:

```
library(dplyr)

iris2 <- iris

myfunction <- function(param) {
 
 result <- if (param=="one") { iris } else if (param=="two") { iris2 } 
 result %>% count(Species) 

}

myfunction(param="one")
myfunction(param="two")
```

Answer (score 1):

With slide modification (you can add more than two conditions)

```
iris2 <- iris

myfunction <- function(param) {
  
  if (param=="one") { 
        return(iris %>% count(Species))
  } 
  
  if (param=="two") { 
       return(iris2 %>% count(Species))
   } 
  
}

myfunction(param="one")
myfunction(param="two")
```

You can also use data.table

```
library(data.table)
iris <- data.table(iris)
iris2 <- iris
myfunction <- function(param) {
  
  if (param=="one") { 
    return(iris[,.N, by= .(Species)])
    } 
  
  if (param=="two") { 
    return(iris2[,.N, by= .(Species)])
  } 
  
}
```